# Request big file url from google stopped working

Tags: google-drive-api

I've noticed that the parameter confirm=no_antivirus for google drive files stopped working. How can I open google drive files now in object tag?

This is what I previously did to display files:

```
 <object data="https://docs.google.com/a/mydomain.com/uc?id=googleid&amp;confirm=no_antivirus#page=495&amp;toolbar=1&amp;navpanes=1" width="100%" min-height="1000px"  height="900px">
        </object>
```

I know it's unsafe to pass the confirm no_antivirus but I'm using this for files from within the domain. Is there another way to display big files now? Small files that don't need the confirmition still work fine.

I'm using the object tag because then I can use the adobe viewer which has more options(open on page x) than the chrome/google one.

Comment: Sorry this is unsupported in the SDK.

Comment: So there's no way of displaying big files(except download)?